# How to resolve randomly app crash on IOS Device?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am using swrevealviewController for sliding from one view to another.
But My app is crashing randomly , When I sliding from one view to another , On every view , There is server call for showing video list.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    //NSLog(@"connection did finish loading %@",responseData);
    //NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSLog(@"tdshjfhdkh %@",str);

    [self.resopnseDelagate carryData:responseData];
    responseData = nil;
}
```

My app is crash in above method randomly and give an error in log as given bellow ::
[viewController retain]:message sent to deallocated instance 0xa081994e

I am also to debug this issue by using Crashlytic ,But unable to understand their log as given below :

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3a78152c objc_retain + 11
1  DemoApp                       0x000d2c81 -[Connection connectionDidFinishLoading:] (Connection.m:76)
2  Foundation                     0x3341a6fd __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke_0 + 16
3  Foundation                     0x3335a1f9 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 200
4  Foundation                     0x3335a115 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 60
5  CFNetwork                      0x327bc45f ___delegate_didFinishLoading_block_invoke_0 + 26
6  CFNetwork                      0x327bbb43 ___withDelegateAsync_block_invoke_0 + 54
7  CFNetwork                      0x327e3fcb ___performAsync_block_invoke_068 + 18
8  CoreFoundation                 0x32a2574d CFArrayApplyFunction + 176
9  CFNetwork                      0x327e442b RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 74
10 CFNetwork                      0x3274803d MultiplexerSource::perform() + 188
11 CoreFoundation                 0x32ab4683 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
12 CoreFoundation                 0x32ab3ee9 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 212
13 CoreFoundation                 0x32ab2cb7 __CFRunLoopRun + 646
14 CoreFoundation                 0x32a25ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
15 CoreFoundation                 0x32a25d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
16 GraphicsServices               0x365e92eb GSEventRunModal + 74
17 UIKit                          0x3493b301 UIApplicationMain + 1120
18 DemoApp 

                  0x000da839 main (main.m:16)
```

Please Help me ,Thanks in Advance.

Comment: are you using ARC or manual memory management?

Comment: Clear Derived data, then quite simulator.

Comment: I am using ARC on Xcode 5.02

Comment: @KDRocks   Can you write code which is responsible for calling `connectionDidFinishLoading` ?

Comment: This is automatically called when I request to server using nsurlconnection NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0f];
    
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    
   NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    
    [connection start];

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a view controller that no longer exists in memory so firstly turn on NSZombies to find out where this is happening [How to enable NSZombie in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode)

Secondly before calling your delegate you should check to ensure its not nil

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    //NSLog(@"connection did finish loading %@",responseData);
    //NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSLog(@"tdshjfhdkh %@",str);

    if([self.responseDelagate respondsToSelector:@selector(carryData:)]) {
        [self.resopnseDelagate carryData:responseData];
    }
    responseData = nil;
}
```

Comment: you are partly right. he is using something thats no longer there - alas messages to nil are totally fine and woundt crash here. the problem likely is that it isnt there but the pointer isnt nil.

Comment: If the delegate method is not marked @optional the only use of the if condition is to hide bugs -> don't do it.

Comment: carryData is a delegate method , which is used to passed received data  to any view controller.and used as in connection.h class @property(assign,nonatomic)id <MyDelegate> resopnseDelagate;

Comment: [viewController retain]:message sent to deallocated instance 0xa081994e  comes after nszombie enabled

Answer (score 0):

try releasing responseData in dealloc like this

```
-(void)dealloc{

 [repsonseData release];
 responseData = nil;
```

}

and also check whether you are setting the responseDelegate before calling a method on it

Comment: I am still getting crash, my problem seem like this link image http://answer.techwikihow.com/554857/corefoundation-trap-error-tread1exc_breakpoint-codeexc_arm_breakpoint-subcode0xdefe.html , Please help me.